# Jinja template rendering in log different than returned response

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a web service that generates configuration files for an application we run.  Parameters are passed in and a configuration is generated based off those parameters.

This is what I am using to generate the configuration files.

```
env=Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates'))                       
        template=env.get_template('squid.conf.j2')
        return template.render(proxy_data=get_proxy_data(vendor=grp_name))
```

When I output the the rendered template to logs they look fine.  However, web requests are doing some kind of encoding and causing the following to occur.  How do I prevent this from happening so the content is written to files properly?

```
"#proxy_auth REQUIRED\n\n##### startconf 3329 #####\nhttp_port 0.0.0.0:3329\nacl port_3329 myport 3329\nhttp_access allow port_3329\ncache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8123 0 default proxy-only no-query \ncache_peer_access 127.0.0.1 allow port_3329\n##### endconf 3329 #####\n\n\n\nacl SSL_ports port 443\nacl Safe_ports port 80\t\t# http\nacl Safe_ports port 21\t\t# ftp\nacl Safe_ports port 443\t\t# https\nacl Safe_ports port 70\t\t#"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging I ended up using something like this to get what I needed.

```
json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))['config']
```